# ShrePoint 2013 - Configuring Forms Based Authentication (LDAP)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, forms-authentication

I am using forms based authentication for our external partners.  I have setup both Windows and forms authentication within the web application's default zone.  I have performed all steps correctly in the following guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806890(v=office.15).aspx.   I am able to add forms users from within Central Admin and within the default zone.

I have extended the web application to an **Intranet zone that is only using Windows authentication**.  However, I am unable to add forms users from within the Intranet zone.  Is this behavior expected?  I would like to manage the web application from within the Intranet zone, is there anyway to connect to the forms based membership provider from with the Intranet to add forms members?

Thank you in advance for your help...

Answer (score 0):

If you add the membershipprovider settings to the intranet zone's web.config, you can use the FBA Pack to manage your users on that zone.

To use the SharePoint tools to add forms users, you could add Forms Based Authentication to the zone, but use a custom login page.  For the custom login page, just point it to SharePoint's built in Windows Authentication login page.